# Mamp/Apache not starting in Mac

Tags: php, apache, web, localhost, mamp

[image: when i start my mamp this pop up comes]

I want to start my mamp but it keep saying Apache could not start as 8888 is in use by some other software while no other apps are open in my MacBook.

It was working fine for a good time and suddenly its been stopped and I have tried closing everything and running only mamp still it is not starting apache.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49342602/10245455

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MAMP "Apache couldn't be started because port is in use." AND "Can’t connect to local MySQL server through /tmp/mysql.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387922/mamp-apache-couldnt-be-started-because-port-is-in-use-and-can-t-connect-to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try changing the port to 8000, 8080 or 80 maybe

Comment: I did it earlier and it works as in mamp u get 8888 port so make it 8881 and that fixes the problem